# Python: Unexpected print values from within a simple function

Tags: python

I have created an simple, arbritrary function that prints out a value (1) based on what the first element from a randomly shuffled list is.

Looking at the code below: I am creating a variable and setting it to 1, then I'm a creating a small list (1,2,3) and then shuffling the list. The idea is, if the first element of that list (after shuffle) is 1 or 2, then print the value of 'correct', BUT if the first element of the list happens to be 3, set 'correct' to 0, and then run the function again. As you can see from the if statement, when 'value' is set to 0, I don't expect this to be printed at all because the function is being run again (chair()) before any printing takes place.

Having run this, I expected to find a print out of 5 values of 1. The problem is, I am seeing 0 values printed too. This seems like a very simple function, and I feel a little but stupid for not seeing why this is happenig. Any ideas?

```
def chair():

    correct = 1

    a = [1,2,3]
    random.shuffle(a)

    if a[0] == 3:
        correct = 0
        chair()               #run function again without printing

    print correct


for i in range(5):
    chair()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is recursive, so when you recall the function again to avoid printing, the function will still finish. If you added an else statement, you'd see those zeros disappear. Ex:

```
def chair():

    correct = 1

    a = [1,2,3]
    random.shuffle(a)

    if a[0] == 3:
        correct = 0
        chair()               #run function again without printing
    else:
        print correct


for i in range(5):
    chair()
```

edit: grammar
edit: example

Comment: Perfect. That small change was exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just calling `chair()` does not modify `correct`.  You need to do `correct = chair()`.  The problem with that is `chair()` does not return anything; it prints it.  You should move the printing to outside of the function and return instead:

```
def chair():

    correct = 1

    a = [1,2,3]
    random.shuffle(a)

    if a[0] == 3:
        correct = chair()

    return correct


for i in range(5):
    print chair()
```

Comment: why can't you just `return chair()` instead of assigning it to `correct`

Comment: @danidee: No reason.  I don't see a benefit either way.

Comment: @danidee Wouldn't that basically make `correct` superfluous? Would the value still be returned to the for loop?

Comment: yes it will...it could simply be removed instead of assigning `chair()` to it again for no reason

Comment: @danidee ah, you mean having two return statements? Replacing `correct = chair()` with `return chair()` and leaving `return correct` as it is? I thought you meant deleting `return correct` and only returning `chair()` from the function (and only `if a[0] == 3`)

Comment: I thought you meant deleting return correct and only returning `chair()` from the function (and only `if a[0] == 3`). yes that's exactly what i meant, even if there are two return statements(for a reason out of this world) the first one will get executed :)

Comment: @danidee Got it! Thanks :)